# "Failed to read SDK values" error

Tags: android, eclipse

When Eclipse opens, the Error Log pops up and gives me this error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Jess D630\Desktop\School\DCMST\Directed Study\eclipse\platforms\android-7\data\service_actions.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.AndroidTargetParser.collectValues(AndroidTargetParser.java:403)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.AndroidTargetParser.collectIntentFilterActionsAndCategories(AndroidTargetParser.java:388)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.AndroidTargetParser.run(AndroidTargetParser.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$5.run(Sdk.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I know that I need the service_actions.txt file but I cannot find it online anywhere. 
I solved a similar problem by finding the source code online for a different file.

Does anyone have the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

That file is referred by the Android SDK. Your SDK and Eclipse configuration is incorrect, that's why you are getting this error. Please refer this guide for setup instructions:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Comment: try deleting everything and re-installing it once. Also check if java (JDK) is installed and configured properly